# Python: Specifying Positions in Lists?

Tags: python

I have three lists, of the form:

```
Day: [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, ..... n, n, n]
Wavelength: [10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30, ..... 10, 20, 30]
Flux: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ..... 1, 2, 3]
```

I want to split the lists so that the sections of the list with the "Day" value of 1 are seperated and run through a function, and the process then repeats and does this all the way through until it has been done for all n days.

I've tried splitting them into lists and currently have:

```
x=[]
y=[]
z=[]

for i in day:
    if Day[i] == Day[i+1]:
        x.append(Day(i))
        y.append(Wavelength[i])
        z.append(Flux[i])
        i+=1
    else "integrate over the Wavelength/Flux values where the value of Day is 1"
        i+=1
```

This doesn't work, and I'm not convinced I'm going about it the best way. I'm relatively new to programming so it still takes me ages to find and fix errors!

Comment: you want to remove duplication???

Comment: `i` in `for i in day:` returns the current `element` not `index`. Use `for index, element in enumerate(day):` instead.

Comment: Are you trying to extract patterns inside list; eg: [1, 2, 3] in Day is repeatedly shown

Comment: Please show us what your expected output is.

Comment: Use Day[i] instead of Day(i)

Comment: if you added some small inputs and some expected output from that it would make your question a lot more obvious

Answer (score 1):

If you use `zip()` to combine the three lists into one list of tuples, you can then filter it for each day you care about. (This isn't particularly efficient if you have lots of data, and will require more memory than your approach, but has the advantage of being, concise, fairly pythonic, and I believe readable.)

```
data = zip(day, wavelength, flux)
for d in range(min(day), max(day)+1):
    print d, [ datum for datum in data if datum[0] == d ]
```

Instead of `print` you could just pass that list (the output of the `[…]` list comprehension) to whatever function you need to run over the data (possibly with `d`, the day you're dealing with at that time).